# ADB keeps disconnecting on MacOS Sierra after 6+ hours

Tags: android, ruby, adb, macos-sierra, calabash

I run long tests in android device which runs for more than 15 hours. After getting updated to MacOS Sierra the adb used to get disconnected immediately after 15 minutes. After checking for solutions I updated to Android SDK Platform-tools 24.0.4. Looks like the issue is partially fixed. Instead of 15 minutes it is getting disconnected after 6 or 7 hours of execution. Never saw this problem on MacOS El Capitan. In MacOS El Capitan I ran tests for 15+ hours and it ran fine.

As many suggested in online blogs to have a shell script to check for adb connection once in 5 seconds and restart if connection is lost. I'm not sure if that would be effective as tests run fine for 6+ hours and then the problem starts. I have also installed Android SDK Platform-tools 25.0.1. Please let me know if anyone is facing the same issue and would appreciate if there is any solution to this.

Comment: can you please post the error message ?

Comment: Please find the error below                                                                           `could not take screenshot
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device '**************' not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:285)
 at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashAdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ddmlib.CalabashDevice.getScreenshot(Unknown Source)
 at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source)`